# Spring Security pathMatchers with changeable query param

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

How can I enable access to the endpoint that has the following path:

```
POST:  /allBooks/{code}/details
```

My SecurityConfig class i Spring Boot app:

```
@Bean
  SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http,
      RedirectUriValidator redirectUriValidator, JwtService jwtService) {
    http.csrf().disable()
        .addFilterAt(qorestorLegacyApiKeyFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
        .authorizeExchange()
            .matchers(new ApiTokenServerWebExchangeMatcher()).permitAll()
            .pathMatchers(
              "/path1/getAllBooks",
              "/path2/getBook",
              "/allBooks/**/details" --> MY ENDPOINT
            ).permitAll()
            ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: What errors do you get? Looks like it should have worked.

Comment: 401 Unauthorized - maybe I should set something like that: /allBooks/{code}/details/**???

Comment: like in this book: https://books.google.pl/books?id=L-U5DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA343&lpg=PA343&dq=spring+security+pathMatchers+path+variable&source=bl&ots=SC4MAVKDF0&sig=ACfU3U0PMr5ovLjWqHyZcPNlmMfZBKB3MA&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjir6aw-M_pAhWps4sKHUdnCG4Q6AEwCXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=spring%20security%20pathMatchers%20path%20variable&f=false

Comment: Doesn't work too... Anybody knows???

Comment: for solutions this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66883174/adding-multiple-spring-security-configurations-based-on-pathmatcher see the tread