# Adding multiple Spring Security configurations based on pathMatcher

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to setup multiple security configurations that will use different `SecurityApiKeyFilter` classes based on the `pathMatchers`, for now I only got 2. One which works for all URLs and one which works only on a URL that contains `admin`. Initially, you are set as a guest and after that, we will try to authorize you based on ApiKey. However, I am not really able to get it to reach the 2nd `SecurityWebFilterChain` configuration. Even though the `pathMatcher` is set as so.

```
@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityWebFilterChain securitygWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http, 
                                                        ClientService clientService) {
    SecurityWebFilterChain filterChain = http.authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .anyExchange().authenticated().and()
            .anonymous().principal("guest").and()
            .addFilterBefore(new SecurityApiKeyFilter(clientService), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
            .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()
            .jwtDecoder(new NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder("/.well-known/jwks.json"))
            .and()
            .and().build();

    return filterChain;
}

@Bean
@Order(2)
public SecurityWebFilterChain sdkJsWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http,
                                                      ClientService clientService) {
    SecurityWebFilterChain filterChain = http.authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "**/admin/**").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("**/admin/**").permitAll()
        .anyExchange().authenticated().and()
        .anonymous().principal("guest").and()
        .addFilterBefore(new Admin.SecurityApiKeyFilter(clientService),
            SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
        .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()
        .jwtDecoder(new NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder("/.well-known/jwks.json"))
        .and()
        .and().build();

    return filterChain;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess it is the same behavoir for reactive applications as for servlet applications.

Your second security filter chain is not executed, because only the first matching security filter chain will be invoked, see [9.4. SecurityFilterChain](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.0/reference/html5/#servlet-securityfilterchain):

> **9.4. SecurityFilterChain**
>
> [...]
>
> In fact, `FilterChainProxy` can be used to determine which `SecurityFilterChain` should be used. This allows providing a totally separate configuration for different *slices* of your application.
>
> [image]
>
> In the Multiple SecurityFilterChain Figure `FilterChainProxy` decides which `SecurityFilterChain` should be used. Only the first `SecurityFilterChain` that matches will be invoked. If a URL of `/api/messages/` is requested, it will first match on `SecurityFilterChain0`'s pattern of `/api/**`, so only `SecurityFilterChain0` will be invoked even though it also matches on `SecurityFilterChainn`. If a URL of `/messages/` is requested, it will not match on `SecurityFilterChain0`'s pattern of `/api/**`, so `FilterChainProxy` will continue trying each `SecurityFilterChain`. Assuming that no other, `SecurityFilterChain` instances match `SecurityFilterChainn` will be invoked.

Comment: It's rare to see an answer explaining the "why" and not just the how, thank you for the detailed explanation and diagram!

Answer (score 3):

if you want to totally separate path patterns from other security web filter chains, you can configure multiple `SecurityWebFilterChain`s by using `securityMatcher` like below.

```
public SecurityWebFilterChain stackSagaEndpoint(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

   http.securityMatcher(new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher("/specific -path/**"))
   ....

}
```

and the execution will depend upon your further configurations like ordering    and global configurations.

Comment: That's right! And you need separate securityMatcher's in different filterChain beans:
`public SecurityWebFilterChain chain1(ServerHttpSecurity http) {`
`   return http.securityMatcher(new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher("match1"))...;`
`}`
`public SecurityWebFilterChain chain2(ServerHttpSecurity http) {`
`   return http.securityMatcher(new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher("match2"))...;`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

I have also found this to be very helpful, in case anyone is looking for another type of solution it's not in Java but you will get the gist.

```
class SecurityConfig {

@Bean
fun getReactiveAuthenticationManager(): ReactiveAuthenticationManager {
    return ReactiveAuthenticationManager { authentication ->
        // simply return the authentication assuming the authentication was already verified in the converter
        Mono.justOrEmpty(authentication)
    }
}

companion object {
    const val ADMIN_RESOURCE_A = "ADMIN_RESOURCE_A"
    const val ADMIN_RESOURCE_B = "ADMIN_RESOURCE_B"
}

@Bean
fun springSecurityFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity,
                              @Qualifier("authFilterResourceA")
                              authFilterResourceA: AuthenticationWebFilter,
                              @Qualifier("authFilterResourceB")
                              authFilterResourceB: AuthenticationWebFilter): SecurityWebFilterChain {

    //configure security for resource a
    http
            .addFilterAt(authFilterResourceA, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/resourceA/**")
            .hasRole(ADMIN_RESOURCE_A)

    //configure security for resource b
    http
            .addFilterAt(authFilterResourceB, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/resourceB/**")
            .hasRole(ADMIN_RESOURCE_B)

    // global config
    http
            .httpBasic()
            .disable()
            .formLogin()
            .disable()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .cors()
            .disable()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .anyExchange()
            .authenticated()

    return http.build()
}

@Bean("authFilterResourceA")
fun authFilterResourceA(authManager: ReactiveAuthenticationManager): AuthenticationWebFilter {

    val filter = AuthenticationWebFilter(authManager)

    filter.setServerAuthenticationConverter {

        // simplified dummy token conversion for keeping the example as simple as possible

        Mono.justOrEmpty(it)
                .map { it.request.headers.getFirst("X-Application-Authentication") ?: "" }
                .filter { it == "Bearer tokenForA" }
                .map {
                    val authentication = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            "userWithAccessRightsToA",
                            it,
                            listOf(SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_$ADMIN_RESOURCE_A"))
                    )
                    logger.info { "Created authentication: $authentication" }

                    authentication as Authentication
                }
    }

    return filter
}

@Bean("authFilterResourceB")
fun authFilterResourceB(authManager: ReactiveAuthenticationManager): AuthenticationWebFilter {

    val filter = AuthenticationWebFilter(authManager)

    filter.setServerAuthenticationConverter {

        // simplified dummy token conversion for keeping the example as simple as possible

        Mono.justOrEmpty(it)
                .map { it.request.headers.getFirst("X-Application-Authentication") ?: "" }
                .filter { it == "Bearer tokenForB" }
                .map {
                    val authentication = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            "userWithAccessRightsToB",
                            it,
                            listOf(SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_$ADMIN_RESOURCE_B"))
                    )
                    logger.info { "Created authentication: $authentication" }

                    authentication as Authentication
                }
    }

    return filter
}
```

Source: https://github.com/jimonthebarn/spring-webflux-multiple-auth-mechanisms/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/localhost/playground/multi/auth/SecurityConfig.kt